# Does nodejs use the module key to publish its es6 API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

The rollup documentation has the following example of importing the `util.ajax` function:

```
import { ajax } from 'utils';
```

Does node expose an ES6 module containing `utils` via the `module` key on package.json and is this the general pattern used by NodeJS?

Update for those wondering what the purpose of the question is - If this is the case then rollupjs can tree shake node modules directly without having to transpile them to ES6 modules first.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It is unclear in your question...

Comment: a little bit of research goes a long way.  There are literally *hundreds* of articles that cover ES6 `import`.  The [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) shows the syntax you are asking about.

Comment: No. You still need to transpile the import to a `require()` call, which includes the `utils` commonjs module.

Comment: Cool - Thanks @Bergi - In this case targeting doing the reverse - transpiling the `utils` module to ES6 such that tree shaking can be performed - turns out there's a rollupjs plugin (rollup-plugin-commonjs) that supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a fictional example of a module that you *could* import. It's not a built-in module like Node's [util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html).